# What algorithm should I use to find the maximum areas in this graph?

Tags: algorithm

As indicated in the image, I am looking for an algorithm that can identify these locations (given a certain threshold). I don't want to have every maximum, just the recognizable ones. 'recognizable' defined by a threshold variable.

[Graph of data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwsLc.png)

I can provide more detailed information upon request. (e.g. data points, what the data actually is, etc)

Comment: How is the data stored? How do you define "threshold"?

Comment: Mathematically, probably something about finding the derivatives, limits, and critical points...

Comment: The data is in an array

Comment: A smaller threshold would mean that the algorithm finds more of the smaller  maximums. 
For instance, a threshold of zero would find every single peak where it meets this criteria, 'x' being the 'x' position on the graph: 
if (peak(x-1) < peak(x) > peak(x+1)) {return all instances of x in the array where this is true)

Comment: @brw59 What if the threshold is not zero? Do you want only local maximums, or on the frontiers too?

Comment: If the frontiers happen to be significantly higher than everything else, then they should always be returned no matter how high the threshold is. There should come a point where the size of the threshold will only allow for one point to be returned (if there's a difference between points), so if it continues to increase, there will still only be one point returned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find local maxima, so I'd suggest a window approach - given any set of N adjacent points as your "window", select the maximum for that window, without repetitions of the same maximum point.

You can either break it into fixed-width areas and check each independently, such that the graph is divided into M separate groups of data points to check, or use a sliding "window" to determine if there is a local maximum surrounded by sufficiently minimum values as to reset the window and allow selecting another maximum nearby (helps with choppy data).

Comment: If I applied what you are saying I'd have to do something like a 'sliding window'; if I use this method, then I don't know how to determine the 'sufficiently minimum values', that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Well, as one possible option, you could do something based on the local maximum that is within the current window, such as anything below 10% of the local maximum resets the window, with the further limitation that anything less than or equal to the local maximum is not allowed to be a local maximum within the same window (to prevent saw-tooth data from registering a large number of maxima).

Comment: The idea is the general direction of a solution I'm trying to find, except I don't want to guarantee that every 'window' has a maximum, or that there is only one maximum per window. If all by data (which is taken from an image, thus can be vastly different) is leaned on the right end of the spectrum I may only have 1 or 2, but both on the right side of the graph, possibly very close to each other.

Comment: If you just want unusually large values, you could just find the highest value, then find anything within some multiple of the standard deviation of that highest value (that wouldn't find your middle example though, since it is barely a local maxima, let alone a high value).  What kind of values are you actually trying to find?  Unusually high values, or locally high values, or the highest within a given region, or the peak of "mountains" (where the slopes on either side of the point have differing signs), or something else?

Comment: Suppose I had a plain picture with some solid color (unknown color of any shape(s)) objects in it in front of a plain solid color background. I am turning this picture into gray scale, organizing the groups of the resulting grayscale pixels that are similar to each other depending on shades, then I'm going to manipulate the original pixels after I am able to differentiate the objects by color from their gray scale pixels.

Comment: Therefore, if I had a white piece of paper with lines drawn on it in two different colors, and a picture was taken of this piece of paper, I want to be able to differentiate the lines and the background in their own separate groups. The background will almost assuredly be dominant in white and would overpower the lines that were drawn on the piece of paper, but I need to get their pixels too.